# EEA family permit visa refusal: appeal or reapply?

Tags: uk, visa-refusals

My application was refused based on only one reason, insufficient proof of financial dependency. My sponsor, who is my father-in-law, sent me money from July 2017 to February 2018 using a local money transfer service. He switched to WorldRemit in March 2018 on the advice of a lawyer that bank transfer was better. This he did until September 2018.

Now, they based their decision on transfers between February to July 2018, despite submitting my account statements that show receipt of funds from March to September 2018.

They said I didn't include receipts of upkeep and rent. I have them but that's only thing I didn't add.

I have a right to appeal. Do I have a strong case for appeal? Should I reapply? We are confused.

Comment: You may get better answers if you post a copy of your refusal notice with personal details blanked out.

Answer (score 3):

The appeal will not consider new evidence.  To have your case considered in light of additional evidence, you must submit a fresh application.

Therefore, you should probably appeal only if your previous application was refused wrongly given the evidence you submitted with it, that is, if there was some error on the part of the Home Office.  Your omission of evidence is not an error on the part of the Home Office.

Comment: Thank you. Error was made on their part cos I submitted my account statement and his. These were not looked at. I will come to share my story after the appeal

Comment: @Amens but "they said I didn't include receipts of upkeep and rent. I have them but that's only thing I didn't add": if the refusal depends on the lack of these receipts then your appeal is likely to fail.  Also note that a fresh application will probably quicker, and it is free.  An appeal can take a long time and costs a bit of money (which you may get back if the appeal succeeds).  You can also reapply and appeal at the same time.  If you are determned to appeal, you should consider doing both.

Comment: Thank you so much for the advice. I will discuss this with my lawyer and see the possibility of doing both. Thanks.